# Access and embed Google Analytics using server-side authorization in PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to display Google Analytics data on my site, but using server-side authorization.

The Google demo shows how to do this with Python, but I'm trying to use PHP. 
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

Here is the code I have. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php         

require_once( 'google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php' );

$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();
function initializeAnalytics()
{
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . 'analytics-serviceacc.json';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("My Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

  $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $token = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

  return $accessToken;
}

echo $accessToken;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Analytics Dashboard</title>      
</head>

<body>

<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
    }(window,document,'script'));
</script>


<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
          serverAuth: {
            access_token: '<?php echo $accessToken ?>'
          }
        });

        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                ids: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-1-container',
                type: 'LINE',
            }
        });
        dataChart.execute();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The access token is retrieved. But the Google Analytics chart still doesn't show up.

But I'm getting the code from Google, so it should work?

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Ahh, apologies, I've added that now.

Comment: what's your service account role? and have you enabled google analytics reporting api?

Comment: Yes, I enabled GA reporting and I am the admin on that service account.

Comment: can you check if the access token is valid and have the scope of `analytics.readonly`, by this api (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken)?

Comment: Ok, I pasted the access token into that URL and I got this 
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
expires_in 3567
access_type "offline"